# Import BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, importerror

To my understanding "import package.module" is same as "from package import module". But this is not behaving as expected in case of BeautifulSoup.

**from bs4 import BeautifulSoup**: This command works fine.

But,

**import bs4.BeautifulSoup** throws the following error

*ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4.BeautifulSoup'*

Any thoughts/help on this?

Comment: because `BeautifulSoup` is not a submodule, but a class...

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Definitely do supply it as an answer, it is a suitable question :)

Comment: install bs4 as it is package , while BeautifulSoup is a class

Comment: @TerryA Thanks! Although I refrained from answering since it should be a duplicate x) (I've definitely seen a similar question somewhere before but, too lazy to look for it...)

Answer (score 4):

As colorspeed pointed out above, BeautifulSoup is a class therefore `import bs4.BeautifulSoup` will result in error. Instead use the syntax `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`.

Answer (score 0):

import bs4.BeautifulSoup will work when we have another file like thing in your bs4 package however BeautifulSoup is a class from that package so it cannot be called the way you are calling it.

Example I have a package name Twitter and there is a sub package called twitter-api then I can call it as **import Twitter.twitter.api**
Similarly, if I have package name Twitter and there is a class inside that package with name twitter-api then I have to call it **from Twitter import twitter-api**